# How to solve this recursive equation?

Tags: induction, recursion

I've got this recursive  equation:

$$
T(n) = \begin{cases} 2, & \text{if $n = 2$} \\ 2T(n/2) + n, & \text{if $n = 2^k$ where k > 1, $k \in \mathbb{N} $} \\ \end{cases}
$$

I know I should use mathematical induction. For $n = 2$, prove is obvious. But for $2n$, it's more difficult:
$$
T(2n) = 2T(n) + n
$$

So how to solve that?

Comment: shouldn't that be $T(2n) = 2T(n) + 2n$?

Comment: @snulty no, that time I'm sure.

Comment: but replace $n$ in your definition by $2n$ the whole way across...

Comment: Like when you write $T(2n)$ you realize that $n$ is a power of two else your function isn't defined?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Satisfy yourself with the first few values that:

\begin{align}
T(2^k)&=2T(2^{k-1})+2^k\\
&=4T(2^{k-2})+2^k+2^k\\
&=8T(2^{k-3})+3\cdot2^k\\
&\vdots\\
&=2^{k-1}T(2^1)+(k-1)\cdot2^k\\
&=2^k+(k-1)\cdot 2^k\\
&=k\cdot2^k
\end{align}

So if we say $2^k=n$ then $T(n)=\log_2(n)\cdot n$

Comment: Now i understand. But you should add something like $2^k = n => k = lg n$

Comment: @enedil I don't follow. You could write your function as 

$T(2^k) = \begin{cases} 2 & \text{if $k = 1$} \\ 2T(2^{k-1}) + 2^k, & \text{if k > 1, $k \in \mathbb{N} $} \newline \end{cases}$ 

given that's the only times it's defined.

Comment: I could, if I was the author of that function. But i'm not.

Comment: @enedil You can because you are the author of the post. You can because you are the one solving the problem. I could call the function $\mathrm{dogs}:\{2^k \mid k \in \Bbb{N}\}\rightarrow\Bbb{N}$, which does the same thing $\mathrm{dogs}(2^k)=\ldots$ It's just notation. You can choose whatever is most convenient. Just say what you are choosing :)

Comment: @enedil Sorry I see what you're saying now. I can add that for clarity if you like. Thanks. See edit

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $n$ is a power of $2$ so that $n = 2^k$ for some $k \in \mathbb N$. Then by unrolling the recursion, observe that:
\begin{align*}
T(n) &= T(2^k) \\
&= 2 \cdot T(2^{k-1}) \\
&= 2^2 \cdot T(2^{k-2}) \\
&= 2^3 \cdot T(2^{k-3}) \\
&= \cdots \\
&= 2^{k-2} \cdot T(2^{2}) \\
&= 2^{k-1} \cdot T(2) \\
&= 2^{k-1} \cdot 2 \\
&= 2^k \\
&= n
\end{align*}

Comment: I'm very sorry :( I wrote the function bad. If you still can resolve that, I'd be pleased. (That which you solved is simple for me).

Answer (score 0):

For small values of $n$, we have $T(2),T(4),T(8),T(16),\ldots=2,8,24,64\ldots$

Can you find a connection between $n$ and $T(n)$?

Let $n=2^k$, and use induction on $k$.  So $U(k)=T(2^k)$, and $U(k+1)=2U(k)+2^k$.

Comment: I can find connection. I even know the answer. But I don't know how to get the answer.